# Android Studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

Just started IDE, chose main activity from suggested list and got an error. I have Intel processor and virtualization enabled and also I had some experience with Android Studio on this laptop a few years ago (it worked fine). Can you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled android studio, deleted all android related folder from the system, then reinstalled it, still got the error. I had to reinstall windows and delete all my files to fix this problem.